# Minimal requirements for funnel plots?

Tags: data-visualization, meta-analysis, funnel-plot

Are there basic minimum requirements for funnel plots to be valid or having a sufficient quality to assess publication bias?

For example in regard to:

1. Numbers of included studies?
2. Size of included studies?
3. ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question could be interpreted in one of two ways. You could be asking whether there are requirements for ***subjective*** evaluations of funnel plots to be considered valid (i.e., looking at a funnel plot and coming to your own conclusion about the presence/absence of small-study effects). Or, alternatively, you could be asking whether there are requirements for ***empirical*** evaluations of funnel plots to be considered valid (i.e., using some sort of statistical test for the presence of small-study effects/publication bias).

mdewey's answer is clearly based on the first interpretation--they offer a heuristic of no less than 10 studies for subjective interpretations of the funnel plot to be valid. I have two problems with this interpretation (to be clear: not mdewey's answer, given the interpretation, but rather, the interpretation itself). First, subjective interpretations of funnel plots can become increasingly difficult to make as the number of studies in the plot increase. For example, with the funnel plot below (~30 effect sizes?) it is pretty easy to visibly detect a superficial amount of asymmetry in the funnel plot. 
[image]

But contrast that plot against one from a much larger meta-analysis (one of my own, below), and you can see that it can become quite unclear how one should interpret a funnel plot when there are many (in this case, 245) effect sizes.
[image]

My second objection to interpreting your question as pertaining to subjective assessment of funnel plots is that I simply struggle to understand how one would define "validity" when the method of inspection is subjective- how can one verify/falsify that their interpretation of the funnel plot is legitimate when there are no empirical criteria being used?

So, I interpret your question as being about empirical evaluations of the funnel plot, and indeed, there are a number of statistical tests you can use to determine whether the funnel plot is significantly asymmetrical. And yes, as you intuit, a number of factors (including the number of effect sizes, the precision of the effect sizes, the variability of effect sizes, whether the effect sizes are heterogeneous, etc.,) impact the validity of these tests. I've included a number of references, below, to simulations of different methods of testing funnel plot asymmetry; most compare methods in terms of their power to detect asymmetry, and their false-positive error rates.

None of these simulations appear to espouse number-of-study guidelines for testing funnel plot asymmetry. A simulation by Sterne, Gavaghan, and Egger (2000), however, does give calculated power levels for a regression method and a correlation method, with varied numbers of studies. The Coles/Kliff notes summary of this simulation is that the authors find that only when there is severe bias(read: easily detected small-study effects), and the number of studies is ~20, does the regression test become adequately powered (power ~.80) to detect funnel plot asymmetry. Thus, **you probably need at least 20 studies** to detect funnel plot asymmetry, and likely will need more unless your data conform to the most optimal conditions for detecting small-study effects. With 10 studies, alternatively, you're only looking at power of ~.30~.50, depending on which test you use (and again, assuming severe bias).

Have a look at the papers too, to see conditions under which false-positives become higher-than-desirable--some methods are better than others for maintaining your false-positive error rate. I'm not sure about other software, but I know the [metafor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor/metafor.pdf) package for R offers users the ability to employ a number of these different methods, depending on their preference (see documentation for the `regtest` command).

**References**

Harbord, R. M., Egger, M., & Sterne, J. A. C. (2006). A modified test for small-study effects in meta-analyses of controlled trials with binary endpoints. *Statistics in Medicine*, *25*, 3443-3457.

Moreno, S. G., Sutton, A. J., Ades, A. E., Stanley, T. D., Abrams, K. R., Peters, J. L., & Cooper, N. J. (2009). Assessment of regression-based methods to adjust for publication bias through a comprehensive simulation study. *BioMed Central Medical Research Methodology*, *9*, 1-17.

Peters, J. L., Sutton, A. J., Jones, D. R., Abrams, K. R., & Rushton, L. (2006). Comparison of two methods to detect publication bias in meta-analysis. *Journal of the American Medical Association*, *295*, 676-680.

Sterne, J. A. C., Gavaghan, D., & Egger, M. (2000). Publication and related bias in meta-analysis: Power of statistical tests and prevalence in the literature. *Journal of Clinical Epidemiology*, *53*, 1119-1129.

Comment: has given us a fascinating example of a funnel plot. One thing which people seldom do is to take advantage of the fact that the regression methods are just that: regression methods. We could apply standard regression diagnostics to them and in the case of the plot he shows ask ourselves whether the outlying points are influential and also just how much of the variability is accounted for by the regressor: precision.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional answer is about 10 studies. The long answer is that you can do anything you want as long as you are careful in what conclusions you draw from it especially if there is much heterogeneity. Perhaps also worth pointing out that strictly speaking what the plot might show is small study bias, publication bias implies you know the aetiology as there are other ways in which small studies may differ.

Comment: A reference for this short convention would probably be helpful, as I am familiar with a few different conventions for # of studies-- it would be good to refer to a researcher's defence of the recommendation.

Comment: As far as I know it is just a convention, I do not think there has been a scientific study showing that 10 was right. Indeed it is fairly hard to see what such a study would consist of.

Comment: Well, sure, if you're just interpreting the funnel plot subjectively, there's going to be no steadfast empirical way to determine how many studies need to be there. But if you are interpreting a funnel plot alongside statistical tests of funnel plot asymmetry,  then you definitely can examine how many studies you need--it's just a power simulation in a meta-analytic context. Begg & Mazumdar, 1994, for an example, did this with the rank correlation test for publication bias, and found that it's well-powered with 75 studies, but much less so with only 25.

Comment: You are right @jsakaluk as I do see the value of plots as enabling us to just look and see anything unexpected. There is rather a good example in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191674/funnel-plot-question which reveals something other than asymmetry

Comment: True, but those sorts of patterns are only likely to be apparent in small meta-analysis where the funnel plot is sparsely populated. I'll try to post an alternative perspective later, but it looks like the original asker just wanted a quick heuristic, and yours seemed to be helpful.