# Sensitivity analysis on secondary outcome

Tags: meta-analysis, methodology, publication-bias, funnel-plot

I plan to perform a meta-analysis with a primary outcome consisting in very rare events (sometimes not occurring in any group of some studies included), and a much more frequent secondary outcome.
To assess the risk of publication bias, I therefore decided to draw a funnel plot based on seconday outcome data.
Is that acceptable? If so, how would I conduct sensitivity analyses related to a possible publication bias?

Comment: This Q&A might be helpful

Comment: @mdewey unless I'm mistaken you forgot to include a link to the Q&A

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193260/minimal-requirements-for-funnel-plots